# Download image from folder with SQL filename

Tags: php, sql

So here I am again :)

Im trying to get a download query to work.
the problem is that the query wont download the uploaded file, it just create an dowload.php file and downloads it to the standard folder,  I wont even have the option to save it where ever I want to. :(

Any ideas what could be the problem ?

download.php

```
if (isset($_GET['file_id'])) {
$file_id = (int)$_GET['file_id'];
$file = mysql_query("SELECT `file_name` FROM `files` WHERE `file_id` = {$file_id}");

if (mysql_num_rows($file) != 1) {
echo 'file ID is invalid';
}
else {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($file);


if (file_exists($path)){
$path = "core/files/{$row['file_name']}";
header('content-Type: application/octetstream');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Description: attachment; filename=\"{$row['file_name']}\"");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$row['file_name']}\"");
```

Also get rid of the closing ?> because it can add extra spaces at the end of the file. It isnt needed.

Comment: hmm, How do you mean echo the contents ?

I still get the error in line 15 =/

Comment: What is on line 15? Sorry I didnt see the readfile() in your code. That echoes the contents of the file.

Comment: I actually solved the problem by moving  $path = "core/files/{$row['file_name']}";
outside the if sats.

But I cant choose saving spot

Comment: I just noticed yoy are checking if $path exists but you dont define it until the next line.

Comment: You using Firefox? Firefox is usually configured to automatically download to predetermined location. It is in the settings.